# ScrollView должен всегда перехватывать onInterceptTouch родителя

Tags: java, android

Имеется кастомный класс `FrameLayout`. В нём я делаю перехват `MotionEvent` в методе `onInterceptTouchEvent`, чтобы реализовать движение моего `FrameLayout`'a. Всё работает, но есть одна проблема. Когда один из дочерних элементов является `ScrollView` (или другой подобный по реализации `ViewGroup`), то начинаются постоянные перебивания. `ScrollView` перестал плавно работать, как раньше. Возникает вопрос: возможно ли сделать так, чтобы `ScrollView` перехватывал все MotionEvent'ы перед тем, как это сделает `FrameLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

Смог найти способ возможно он не такой хороший как мог быть, но работает.

```
private boolean isTouchOnScrollView(MotionEvent event, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            if (child instanceof ScrollView) {
                int[] location = new int[2];
                child.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                Rect bounds = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0] + child.getWidth(), location[1] + child.getHeight());
                if (inBounds(bounds, event.getRawX(), event.getRawY())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (isTouchOnScrollView(event, (ViewGroup) child)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean inBounds(Rect bounds, float x, float y) {
    if (bounds.left < x && bounds.right > x && bounds.top < y && bounds.bottom > y) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isTouchOnScrollView(ev, this)) {
        return false;
    }

    ...
    
    return shouldIntercept;
}
```